# SqlCommand ExecuteReaderAsync helper method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

The following helper method executes commands asynchronously and returns a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` where T is a type that receives the row information from the `SqlDataReader` rows. All works fine.

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> CommandExecuteReaderAsync<T>(SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans, CommandType commandType, string commandText, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters, CancellationToken token, int commandTimout)
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn, trans))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = commandTimout;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            using (var sr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(token))
            {
                var dc = new System.Data.Linq.DataContext(conn);

                return dc.Translate<T>(sr).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I'm not happy with my current approach of creating a new `DataContext` and using it's `Translate<T>` method.

Is there a better approach as the creation of the DataContext seems a bit excessive?

Comment: Please explain what this `DataContext` is? Ideally add it to the question.

Comment: It seems to be a Linq2Sql DataContext.

Comment: @t3chb0t - Apologies, I've edited the original post. Its the System.Data.Linq.DataContext type.

Answer (score 4):

#### DataContext

> [..]the creation of the DataContext seems a bit excessive

Why do you think so? Is creating the `SqlCommand` not excessive? You are instantiating it the same number of times.

If `DataContext.Translate` helps you to save time by not writing the mapping your self then I'd say it's fine. Just remember that `DataContext` is a disposable type too, so you should add one more `using` for it.

---

#### Naming

Apart from the `DataContext` you should try to make you code more consistent. This means, don't use abbreviations like `conn` or `trans`. Use full words especially for parameters.

---

#### Style

> ```
> public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> CommandExecuteReaderAsync<T>(
>   SqlConnection conn, 
>   SqlTransaction trans, 
>   CommandType commandType, 
>   string commandText, 
>   IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters, 
>   CancellationToken token, 
>   int commandTimout)
> ```

I hope you have some overloads for this method. 7 (!) parameters, this is a lot. You should try to reduce them and in fact you can *hide* at least three.

If you make it an extension for the `SqlConnection` then you'll have one parameter less that you have to specify.

If you use `TransactionScope` then you can get rid of the second parameter, the `SqlTransaction`.

If you write two more helper methods (`ExecuteQueryAsync` & `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync`) that call this method, then you can get rid of the `CommandType` parameter.

So no you just have four parameters left that you must specify: `commandText`, `cancelltionToken` & `commandTimeout` & `parameters`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I did mark up your answer but my low rating doesn't add to the count! Thank again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not happy with your current approach of creating a new `DataContext` and using it's `Translate<T>` method either. The task at hand, ostensibly, is convert an `IDataReader` to a generic type `T`.. much like an O/RM would do. Mixing raw ADO.NET and O/RM technologies seems odd. Why not just use Entity Framework, nHibernate, or Dapper? The code to do what you're wanting is pretty complex - that's why whole products exist to do just this. A simple path (which I would not recommend, for performance and corner-case reasons) would go something like this:

```
List<T> resultSet = new List<T>();

while (sr.Read())
{
    T row = new T();

    for (int i = 0; i < sr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (sr.GetValue(i) != DBNull.Value)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(sr.GetName(i));

            propertyInfo.SetValue(row, sr.GetValue(i), null);
        }
    }

    resultSet.Add(row);
}

return resultSet;
```